# Zoomable Treemap with more than two levels, D3plus?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3plus

I would need to create a zoom able treemap using D3plus with more than two levels of zoom.
It should be something like http://d3plus.org/examples/advanced/9860411/

Basically, I am using D3plus instead of D3 because I want to use its scaffolding
to create treemap in a easier way.

Anyway, in D3 it is already done http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy in D3plus and you can have as many zoom levels as desired by including additional level(node) information in the data array.

It's dependent on two things:

Data is a flat json structure and includes the relationship of the nodes to each other (parent, child, etc):

```
var sample_data = [
    {"value": 100, "name": "alpha", "group": "group 1", "details": "example 1"},
    {"value": 100, "name": "alpha", "group": "group 1", "details": "example 2"},
    {"value": 100, "name": "alpha", "group": "group 1", "details": "example 3"},
    {"value": 70, "name": "beta", "group": "group 2", "details": "example 1"},
    {"value": 70, "name": "beta", "group": "group 2", "details": "example 2"},
    {"value": 40, "name": "gamma", "group": "group 2", "details": "example 1"},
    {"value": 40, "name": "gamma", "group": "group 2", "details": "example 2"},
    {"value": 15, "name": "delta", "group": "group 2", "details": "example 1"},
    {"value": 15, "name": "delta", "group": "group 2", "details": "example 2"},
    {"value": 5, "name": "epsilon", "group": "group 1", "details": "example 1"},
    {"value": 5, "name": "epsilon", "group": "group 1", "details": "example 2"},
    {"value": 1, "name": "zeta", "group": "group 1", "details": "example 1"}
  ]
```

Notice that the each `name` identifies which `group` it belongs to.  In this case the `group` is the parent node, and the `name` is the child.

Use the `.id()` method to instruct the d3plus on how many levels to include and their order. Using the data structure above and including the third zoom level of "details" would be: `.id(["group","name", "details"])` [d3plus id() documentation and example here](https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/wiki/Visualizations#id)

[Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kz9XX/22/)